# Mysql locate, with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with mysql's locate.

My Table `test` looks like this:

row  => type

id   => int
data => string

When I try to execute `SELECT LOCATE("searchString",  (SELECT data FROM`test`LIMIT 2))`

I allways get 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'.

How can I solve this Problem? I just want to select all rows where my search string is part of the data row. Is it even possible to do this with mysql?

**UPDATE:**

This is just a subquery. The hole query will look something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM anamnese WHERE STRCMP("01.01.2012", (SELECT SUBSTRING(
                                              FROM ( SELECT LOCATE ... )
                                              FOR (SELECT LOACTE ....)+10)
                                 = 0
```

So I have to search for a date within some string which are stroed in the database.
And I can't change'anything on the database!

Comment: Why do you not know which field your date will be in?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) query. This will return all rows where the `data` column contains the word 'searchString':

```
SELECT `data` FROM `test` WHERE `data` LIKE '%searchString%';
```

Comment: YES, but this part of the query ist just a subquery. I have to search for the string and after that I have to compare it. So 'LIKE' is not an option for me.

Comment: @samsemilia7 Will you elaborate? What are you comparing?

Answer (score 0):

`LOCATE(substr, string)`

If you want that to work, you need to put "LIMIT 1" instead of "LIMIT 2" in your query.

Anyway i suppose that it's not what you're looking for.

Source: [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

Comment: thanks for the replay, but I know it works with LIMIT 1. My Problem is, what to do when there are multiple rows